# Limit as $h$ approaches 0 of integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f(x)$ is integrable on an open interval containing $[a,b]$ and is continuous at $a$ and $b$. How can I prove that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}dx = f(b)-f(a)$$

I was thinking of using the fundamental theorem of calculus, but we don't have the condition that $f$ is continuous, only that $f$ is continuous on $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
 For $|h|$ small and not $0$, your expression is equal to
 $$f(b)-f(a)+\frac{1}{h}\int_b^{b+h}(f(t)-f(b))dt-\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h}(f(t)-f(a))dt$$

Comment: I think I get the intuition behind it, but how do you rigorously show this?

Comment: Write $$\int_a^b=\int_a^{a+h}+\int_{a+h}^{b+h}+\int_{b+h}^b$$ and use the change of variable $x=t+h$ for one of the integrals

Comment: How can I prove that if $h$ is small, then $\int_{a}^{a+h} \frac{f(x+h)}{h} = f(a)$. Am I going in the right direction here?

Comment: You have to prove that $I(h)=\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h}(f(t)-f(a))dt\to 0$ as $h\to 0$(and the same for $b$). Given an $\varepsilon>0$, there exist (by the continuity of $f$ at $a$) an $\alpha>0$ such that if $|t-a|<\alpha$, you have $|f(t)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$. If you take $h$ such that $|h|<\alpha$, this gives to you $|I_h|<\varepsilon$.